# Order by or Sort by without column in results

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to do order by or sort by in Hive SQL but not having the column in the results?

For example:

```
| name | num |
|------|-----|
| bob  | 2   |
| dan  | 1   |
| lee  | 3   |
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY num
```

But I got this error:

> Invalid table alias or column reference 'num'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery that does order by and select only the required columns from your main select query

```
   hive> SELECT name FROM (select * from table ORDER BY num) ct;
```